# How to Pad Top of ListView with Space Before First Item in LargeIcon View

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I am working with a ListView in LargeIcon View.  I cannot figure out how to pad the top of the ListView with some space before the first ListViewItem.  I've tried adjusting the padding but, it does not seem to have any affect.  Can someone please tell me how to get more space between the top of the ListView and the first ListViewItem?  I have included a screenshot of the ListView that contains one item in LargeIcon view below.  The arrow is where I'd like to have a little more white space.  Thanks in advance.

[image: ListView Screenshot]

Comment: Is my answer valid for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Insert your ListView into a panel
- Change the docking of the panel to Fill
- Change the docking of the ListView to Fill, too.
- Finally add TopPadding to your panel.